# Decode barcode from scanned document

Tags: c#, .net, zxing

I'm using the ZXing library for .NET and I can't get a result from the provided image.
After the second to last line, `result` is set to null, because the BarcodeReader didn't detect any barcodes in the image.
Is there something I'm missing about how to set up the BarcodeReader?

```
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader()
{
    AutoRotate = true,
    TryInverted = true,
    Options = new DecodingOptions
    {
        TryHarder = true,
        PureBarcode = true,
        PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.CODE_39 }
    }
};

LuminanceSource source = new ZXing.BitmapLuminanceSource(bitmapImage);
Result result = reader.Decode(source);

Console.WriteLine(result == null ? "Nothing" : result.Text);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you stepped through to see what the value of result is being set to or when you are getting the error?

Comment: @developerIntern53718 I have stepped through, it doesn't give me any exceptions, the only "error" is that the barcode is not detected in the image. After the second to last line, `result` is null.

Comment: well that is the error then... if the barcode is not being recognized in the image than there is nothing to set to result.  Have you tried multiple barcodes to rule out the barcode itself being the issue?

Comment: I suggest trying a computer generated barcode image, rather than a scan. It might just be the image quality.

Comment: @Blorgbeard The second image works just fine. Generated off a website. Is there some way to binarize images in ZXing? Maybe that would help it find the barcode in the scanned document.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XZing.. I did find this: http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx - and your image indeed does not decode. Neither does [this version](http://i.imgur.com/1euKuCi.png) that I "enhanced". It may just be too low resolution. But you could try various tweaks to the image and test them with that website before attempting to code them up.

Comment: nfortunately, zxing is optimized for camera stream interpretation, ie. multiple slightly different images, it doesn't provide a lot of possibilities to improve recognition of scans.

Comment: @ths would you know of any other .NET barcode library to try out instead?

Comment: no, i've been searching myself...

Answer (score 0):

The ZXING does not do any image processing. It simply samples certain points from image using its inner algorithm. (In 2D barcode, a set of points would likely be read from left to right in the center line)

If the image is too low in resolution like the one you show. It is very likely that ZXING did not recogzine it.

What you can do is write your own image binarization method. A simple method would be to set a threshold value, maybe 128 if the pixal range from 0-255. Assign all value above to be 255, all value lower to be 0. The post-processed image may be better for ZXING recognization.